# Is it possible to dynamically allocate the extra memory required for a derived class from an existing base class?

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-management

Is it possible to have a derived class add the extra memory to a pointer that is returned from somewhere else?

The reasoning is I am using a library that returns `Base *` to me, and I add some extra functionality to it with `Derived *`. The problem is I have to create a whole new object when doing this currently and am losing the original pointer which is used internally by the library for updates.

Example of what I am trying to do in simple code:

```
class Base 
{
public:
  Base() {}
  ~Base() = default;

  void BaseMethod();
private:
  int foo;
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
  Derived() : Base() {}
  ~Derived() = default;

  void DerivedMethod();
private:
  int bar;
}

// Somewhere else
Base* baseClass = new Base();

// This is the important part/question. 
// Is there some way to "allocate" the missing memory to make "baseClass" a Derived?
// I don't want to allocate an entirely new object, I just want to find out if it 
// is possible to allocate the missing memory to make Base a Derived 
// (and use the same pointer still)
Derived* derivedClass = SomehowAddExtraMemoryTo(baseClass);
```

Comment: If the library exposes the class like this and allows for inheritance, are you sure it has no facilities to make your life easier? IOW, if you can't initialize your objects, you may not be supposed to do inheritance.

Comment: Short answer is no, if the other library is holding a pointer internally, there's nothing you can do to change that. But your library maybe have some facilities to tell it to allocate `Derived` in the first place. Or you may simply be trying to solve the wrong problem.

Comment: Unfortunately the library does not have this type of support. This is why I was trying to find out if there was something I wasn't aware of on how to do this type of allocation. I believe it is not possible, but just wanted some outside opinions.

Comment: Any specific reason you have to inherit from `Base`? Having `Base*` as a member & adding an implicit conversion operator to `Base` should go a long way replacing inheritance.

Comment: Note that it may be the intention of the library that *it* controls the lifetime of all `Base` objects. Messing with that could easily be undefined behaviour. Note that its by default a bad idea to derive from a class which does not have a virtual destructor

Comment: You might have your own `operator new`, but I am not sure it would be a good idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No this is not possible: essentially there's no C style `realloc` available that will somehow turn a `Base*` into a `Derived*`.

But a "pattern" I've seen in the past involves *both* inheriting from `Base` *and* storing a pointer to a `Base` in `Derived`:

```
class Derived : public Base
{
    Base* b;
};
```

You then write a method in `Derived` to *attach* a `Base` pointer. That is the technique you use to introduce the extra functionality. The fact that your keep `Base` in the inheritance means that you can pass a `Derived*` as a `Base*` where necessary.

Of course this has its dangers. You have to be *really* careful in all the methods to use the correct pointer `b` or the base class `this`. Plus you have to take care when destroying `b` on destruction. As a bare minimum I'd make `Derived` non-copyable if that's possible.

Comment: Yeah this is the only solution I came up with at the moment, but if there is no other way to do it I will have to go with this approach.

Comment: This is a *very dangerous anti-pattern*. Your derived class contains a irrelevant base class copy which might only be default-initialized. When you use the derived class as a base class, the actions are applied to the dummy part, not the real base class in the pointer.

Comment: @liliscent: +1 and indeed it is dangerous and I hope I make that clear! I invite the community to downvote if they feel that changes to the library is the only feasible option. In that way future readers can gauge how folk feel about the above technique.

Comment: The redundant base class can be replaced in most places by `operator Base&() { return *b; }` - Should work the same in most cases.

Comment: @StoryTeller: Indeed it would. But then you lose the relationship between a `Base*` and a `Derived*`. This question might benefit from an answer by you - you know the language better than I do.  I'd upvote...